# Using HashMap Value to remove object from TreeSet

Tags: java, hashmap, treeset

I have a `HashMap` where key is a character and value is some user-defined object. I am adding same objects in the `TreeSet`. The number of entries in `HashMap` and `TreeSet` are equal.

Later on I want to retrieve a object from `HashMap` using user supplied character input. 
Upon retrieving object from `HashMap`, I want to delete the same object from the `TreeSet`. However, the `TreeSet.remove()` doesn't identify the object.

```
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Trial {

char c;
int count;  
HashMap<Character, Trial> map;
TreeSet <Trial> set;

public Trial(char c, int count)
{
    this.c = c;
    this.count = count;
    map = new HashMap<Character, Trial>();
    set = new TreeSet<Trial>(new New_Comparison());     
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Trial root = new Trial('0', 0);
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 26; i++) //add all characters a-z with count 0-25 resp. in root
    {
        char ch = (char)('a' + i);
        Trial t = new Trial(ch, i);
        root.map.put(ch, t);
        root.set.add(t);            
    }

    System.out.println(root.set.size()); //size = 26
    Trial t = root.map.get('c');
    if(t == null)
        return;
    root.set.remove(t);     
    System.out.println(root.set.size());        //size remains the same, expecting 25

}

}
```

Comparator class:

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class New_Comparison implements Comparator <Trial>{

public int compare(Trial n1, Trial n2) {
    if(n1.c <= n2.c)
        return 1;
    return -1;
}


}
```

Output :
26
26

Please help. If the object is either `String or Integer, TreeSet.remove()` works perfectly. But doesn't work for user-defined objects.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `compare` method of the `New_Comparison` comparator you use to create the `TreeSet` never returns 0, so it means that, as far as the `TreeSet` is concerned, no two `Trial` elements are equal.

That's why `set.remove(t)` doesn't remove anything.

Change it to :

```
public int compare(Trial n1, Trial n2) {
    if(n1.c < n2.c)
        return 1;
    else if (n1.c > n2.c)
        return -1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So hashcode is not compared? Compare method is invoked?

Comment: @Curious hashCode + equals are used in HashSet and HashMap. TreeMap and TreeSet use the Comparator (or the natural ordering of the class if you don't supply a Comparator)

Answer (score 1):

Implement your compare method as if two values are equal your compare method will fail.

```
public int compare(Trial n1, Trial n2) {
   return  n1.c.compareTo(n2.c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Comparator is wrong, try this

```
public int compare(Trial n1, Trial n2) {
    return n1.c - n2.c;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

One approach that i would be use, without implementing the comparator is contains() method of TreeSet. It's one way, but how to do the logic is your choice.

```
if(root.set.contains(t)){
    root.set.remove(t); 
}
```